# Is there a way to select descending elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working for `rating` with HTML/CSS.

You can check the example below.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li:hover, li:hover ~ li {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
</ul>
```

As you see, when I `hover` the `li`, I am getting sibling elements are getting `red`. Instead I wanted descending elements are getting `red`.

And I don't want my rating is displayed with inverted color - like all `red` but selections are `gray`. This is not what I wanted.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
}

ul li:hover, li:hover ~ li {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
</ul>
```

How about adding `float: right;` for `ul li`?
I think this is the way you wanted. Thanks

Comment: amazing! - It's working fine. thanks @Alona

Comment: @GeorgeWang—note that this reverses the order of the elements vs the OP. Also they're all siblings, not descendants (but I found that part of your quesiton confusing).

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li:hover, li:hover ~ li {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
  <li>@</li>
</ul>
```

How about using `flex`? It provides `row-reverse`. Thanks

Comment: This is also the good way. But not I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method, in case the order of ratings must be left intact.

I'm setting all ratings to "selected" when the `<ul>` is hovered over.
Then, I set siblings that follow the hovered `<li>` element back to "unselected".

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul:hover li {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

li:hover ~ li {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And I don't want my rating is displayed with inverted color - like all red but selections are gray. This is not what I wanted. @showdev

Comment: @GeorgeWang Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. The result is the same as the answer you said worked for you.

Comment: The way I want is not - `all red but sibling is gray`. The way I want was - `only sibling is red`. Maybe this helps you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sibling". All of the `<li>` elements are siblings of each other. In my example, if you hover over element #3, then elements #1-3 are turned red with white text and elements #4-5 remain white with gray text. It's the same behavior as the other answer, just a different method. It seems you might want something different, but I'm not understanding.

Comment: @GeorgeWang—all the LIs are siblings, hovering doesn't change that. This does exactly what Alona's answer does, but keeps the elements in their expected order rather than reverses them.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code :

```
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let itm = li.length; i-- ;) {
   // reverese li are available here. put your logic here like below
   // li[i].parentNode.appendChild(li[i]);
}
```